# 32 byte aligned allocator for aligned eigen map

Tags: eigen

I use the Eigen Map<> template class to reinterpret chunks of C++ arrays as
Eigen fixed sized arrays. It seems that the Eigen::allocator provided 
16 bytes aligned allocation. What is the proper way to deal with AVX ?
Should I build my own allocator ?

`using Block=typedef Eigen::Array<float,8, 1>;`

`using Map=Eigen::Map<BLOCK,Eigen::Aligned32>;`

`template <class T> using allocator=Eigen::aligned_allocator<T>;`

`std::vector<float,allocator<float> > X(10000);`

`Map myMap(&X[0]); //should be 32 bytes aligned for AVX`

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is outdated, internally Eigen::aligned_allocator is a wrapper around `Eigen::internal::aligned_malloc` that returns memory aligned as defined [there](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html):

> EIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES - Must be a power of two, or 0. Defines an upper
>   bound on the memory boundary in bytes on which dynamically and
>   statically allocated data may be aligned by Eigen. If not defined, a
>   default value is automatically computed based on architecture,
>   compiler, and OS. This option is typically used to enforce binary
>   compatibility between code/libraries compiled with different SIMD
>   options. For instance, one may compile AVX code and enforce ABI
>   compatibility with existing SSE code by defining
>   EIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=16. In the other way round, since by default AVX
>   implies 32 bytes alignment for best performance, one can compile SSE
>   code to be ABI compatible with AVX code by defining
>   EIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=32.

So basically, if you compile with `-mavx`, you'll get 32 bytes aligned pointers.